# Make span clickable inside a clickable row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
$(".clickable").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).data("target");
});
$(".clickableB").click(function() {
  alert('I got a click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee</th>
      <th>Total hours</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#events-modal" class="clickable success">
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>This is a very loooooooooooooooooooong text</td>
      <td>
        <span style="color:green" class="clickableB fa fa-check-square"></span>
        <span style="color:orange" class="clickableB fa fa-warning"></span>
        <span style="color:red" class="clickableB fa fa-minus-square"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="events-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 400px">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Then, what I want to get is to show a modal when a click in the row but get an alert when I click on the icons/spans. Everytime I click in the icons, the modal shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of event bubbling. To prevent it use `stopPropagation`:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(evt) {
  window.location = $(this).data("target");
});
$(".clickableB").click(function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation()
  alert('I got a click');
});
```

That way, when you click a row it will open the modal, but when clicking the span, it will only alert without opening the modal

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You bind it to every td that isnt a `.noclick` and use .parent to get the data target.

```js
$(".clickable td:not(.noclick)").click(function() {
  console.log("modal click");
  window.location = $(this).parent().data("target");
});
$(".clickableB").click(function() {
  alert('I got a click');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee</th>
      <th>Total hours</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#events-modal" class="clickable success">
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>This is a very loooooooooooooooooooong text</td>
      <td class="noclick">
        <span style="color:green" class="clickableB fa fa-check-square"></span>
        <span style="color:orange" class="clickableB fa fa-warning"></span>
        <span style="color:red" class="clickableB fa fa-minus-square"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Now it's working, thank you, sir. The only problem now is that after exiting from alert it opens the modal. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Zariweya you may have an out of date version of what i put. Just double check you used the up to date post and let me know :)

Comment: It's ok now. I used @fatman version and it fixed all problems. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Zariweya no problem, but be careful of using that way as it can cause issues later down the line if you use it a lot and use lots of click events.

Answer (score 0):

it could help you:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass("clickableB")) {
        alert('I got a click');
    }
    else {
        window.location = $(this).data("target");
    }
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is no data inside `clickableB` span class, you need to add some text or image then it will be work

```js
$(".clickable").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).data("target");
});
$(".clickableB").click(function() {
  alert('I got a click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee</th>
      <th>Total hours</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#events-modal" class="clickable success">
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>This is a very loooooooooooooooooooong text</td>
      <td>
        <span style="color:green" class="clickableB fa fa-check-square">clickableB</span>
        <span style="color:orange" class="clickableB fa fa-warning">clickableB</span>
        <span style="color:red" class="clickableB fa fa-minus-square">clickableB</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: He is using fontawesome. Also those spans are not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<span style="color:green" class="clickableB fa fa-check-square"></span>
```

i would just use

```
<span onclick='functionOfChoice();' style="color:green"> ....
```